# Why HOC are applied during exporting of component in place of importing it

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, commonjs

My basic understading is that HOC like connect (for connecting with redux store) and other HOC's are applied to a component while exporting it.

Like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import myHoc from './myHoc/index';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      </div>);
  }
}
export default myHoc({})(App);
```

Where as a better thing would be to apply HOC during import as it would make it easier to make reusable component. The same component can pick up props from store or from props and that would be the responsibility of the parent component to check what to give which HOC to apply on the component.

I know we can use container components which takes the component and render children but that just adds code in the JSX (wont look good if there are many container components)

though we can do it like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import myHoc from './myHoc/index';
import AppChild from './AppChild';
const NewAppChild = myHoc({}, ()=> {
})(AppChild);
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 1,
  };

  reRender = () => {
    this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <NewAppChild handleClick={this.reRender} count={this.state.count}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

What my question is that, is there something better that can handle this kind of situations where I want to apply my HOC on import that is each many container components can import it and they can apply different HOCs depending on the needs.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single concrete reason for this design choice - as you have already seen you can invoke your HOC wherever you use the component - but I see at least 1 advantage: **configuration & component reuse**.

In your example, `myHoc` takes no parameters or configuration so this doesn't necessarily apply, but imagine instead that you are invoking `connect` from redux.

In most use cases, `connect` accepts 2 configuration functions -
 `mapStateToProps` & `mapDispatchToProps` - that define the behaviour.  If you define those within `MyComponent` then any consuming component can `import MyComponent from 'MyComponent'` and start using it.

If you instead rely on the parent component to call `connect()` then you are forcing every consumer to re-implement the configuration of `connect` as well.  That may mean many instances of duplicated configuration and adds to the complexity for consuming components.

That being said, there are certainly cases where you might *want* this behaviour - for example, if you wanted to `connect` the same component to different state definitions.  Ultimately you need to pick the best pattern to support what you need from the component.